# Multiple Variations of UI for the same view controller

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I am working on an Exercise App, where UI depends on the type of Exercise. Some exercises have the question as text and answer as text. Some exercises have the question as text and answer as images. One more variation is image and text in question and image in the answer. I create a question object based on the values I get from API for a particular Exercise. That object has many fields as optional. For example, the image is optional. Now the challenge I am facing is what is the best way to handle such dynamic UI. In plain English, if it has the image, show the imageView and if it doesn't have the image, don't show the imageView and adjust other UI elements accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can have one UIViewController subclass, and many different storyboards each with a different layout and subviews.

- Each storyboard has the view controller's class set to your custom class in the identity inspector.
- Your view controller has outlets for all possible subviews, and each storyboard connects its subviews to the outlets that are relevant to it.
- When you need to present a particular variation of the string, you instantiate your view controller from a case-specific storyboard (programmatically or using segues and storyboard references).

---

If you only need to disable one particular subview in one case, you can do one of the following:

- Set that subview's isHidden property to `false`. It will stay in place, and occupy the same area, but invisible.
- Remove it from the main view by calling `removeFromSuperview()`. Be careful if other, remaining subviews rely on constraints against the removed subview for their layout, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I have a question though. Let's say you have two variations of a view: one with imageView and one without imageView. If we create two storyboards for it, wouldn't it be overkill? Because, rest of the stuff would be the same, but we would still be creating duplicate outlets for them because they are in different storyboards. Please correct me if I am thinking in the wrong direction.

Comment: In that particular case, you can do several things, like change the value of the `isHidden` property to `false`, remove it from superview (this will affect autolayout costraints with other subviews though). See the updated answer.

Comment: the problem with the isHidden solution is that it would still occupy the space, it would just not show it. if I want to go removeFromSuperview route, I have to make sure no other views depend on it. Right? Do you think stackView would be a good solution? because stackview can adjust itself even if you remove an element.

Comment: Yes, I think stack view should work; it takes care of the layout between the stacked components. Hard to say in more detailwithout knowing your exact layout, though.